# FPGA TCP implementation

Tags: tcp, fpga

Does anybody know of an implementation of TCP on a FPGA **WITHOUT** using any sort of microblaze? Preferably open source, because it is for an university/research project.

Comment: Did that in one of my elective EE classes about 10 years ago, it was a project for the whole class (some of us did Ethernet, others IP, others ARP, others TCP).

Comment: OpenCores (http://opencores.org/project,tcp_socket) seems to implement a TCP server on an FPGA.

Answer (score 2):

I know [Easics](http://www.easics.com/) has a TCP core. You can find a presentation on it [here](http://www.hardwareconference.nl/fileadmin/uploads_redactie_hw/2011/Sprekers/Presentaties/Tim_Morlion.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want you maybe can get away with a relative small own implentation (e.g. for packet inspection). The statefulness of TCP makes an full hardware implementation  vary big and cumbersome. If possible I would recommend to switch to UDP, that makes it much easier.

As project dealing with all the IP stuff I know [NetFPGA](http://netfpga.org), but I never checked their design, so it could be, that they utilize internal a microblaze for some stuff, but my guess would be not.

EDIT: I also remember, that I met one someone from the University of Copenhagen (not sure about this point) at a conference, who also implemented TCP stack on Xilinx FPGAs.

Comment: The thing about TCP is, that one can be sure a package was recieved. The data that should be transmitted should really be recieved. Using a microblaze isn't an option, because the data can only be read without it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know both [Intelop](http://www.intilop.com/) and [Velocytech](http://www.velocytech.com/) have commercial TCP/IP cores available

Answer (score 1):

A full and low latency TCP/IP Hardware Stack is also available at [PLDA](https://www.plda.com/tcpip)

Comment: Any chance you are affiliated with that product?